# How to change textview height constraint within table view cell?

Tags: ios, textview, autolayout, constraints

There's been a lot of questions about how to make dynamic cell height using Autolayout and TextView inside it. Here's the story

1. I follow this article [iOS dynamic table view cells with varying row height and Autolayout](http://www.fantageek.com/1468/ios-dynamic-table-view-cells-with-varying-row-height-and-autolayout/). In this case, we replace the 2nd label in the article with a TextView, with the same set of constraints
2. The TextView does not have intrinsic content size as the Label. So we must use `sizeThatFits` and creating height constraint on the TextView, like this.

This height constraint is an IBOutlet from the Nib

`ViewController.m`

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    Item *item = self.dataSource.items[indexPath.row];
    [self.prototypeCell configureWithModel:item];

    [self.prototypeCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

    self.prototypeCell.textViewHeightConstraint.constant = [self.prototypeCell.textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.prototypeCell.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)].height;

    [self.prototypeCell updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    [self.prototypeCell layoutIfNeeded];

    return [self.prototypeCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
}
```

`CustomCell.m`

```
- (void)configureWithModel:(Item *)model {
    self.textView.text = model.content;
}
```

3. I then see in the console that

> ```
> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
>   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to
> ```
>
> figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the
>   unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing
>   NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer
>   to the documentation for the UIView property
>   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
>       (
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           "",
>           ""
>       )
>
> ```
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
> <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa3e3988a90 UITextView:0x7fa3e210f000.height == 200>
> ```

Here you can see that the Autolayout system removes the height constraint on the TextView.

The problem here is that we update the height constraint on the TextView, but the `contentView` of the cell seems to ignore this.

I know the key to this dynamic height is that the subviews (Label, TextView) must determine its own size (Label has its own intrinsic content size, for TextView we manually set its height constraint) so that the `contentSize` is then calculated

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your textViewHeightConstraint an IBOutlet in your CustomCell?

Comment: @BHendricks yes, it is

Comment: Could you show the constraints on the textview in IB? Are you constraining it to 200 initially (the height of the textview) and then trying to programmatically change it?

Comment: @BHendricks 200 is the result of the `sizeThatFits`, the initial value of the height constraint in IB is another value

Comment: Have you tried forcing layout after setting the constraint? I just looked over my code that does this type of behavior, and I force layout with layoutSubviews() after setting the constraint manually in code.

Comment: @BHendricks just updated my question. I tried calling `updateConstraintsIfNeeded ` and `layoutIfNeeded ` but it does not seem to work

Comment: Have you tried explicitly calling layoutSubviews?

Comment: @BHendricks I just explicitly called it, not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77232/discussion-between-bhendricks-and-onmyway133).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply lowering the priority of the `textViewHeightConstraint` (below 1000) fixes the `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints` problem