# What is the proper way to animate custom table view cell constraint change

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, swift3, uiviewanimation

I have asyncimage view in table view custom cell and height constraint for
the image view.

After the completion of image download, i have to increase
the height of cell. so i am changing the height constraint's constant.

```
// cell.swift

self.heightConstraint.constant = image.size.height
self.delegate?reloadTableView()

// viewcontroller.swift

func reloadTableView()
{
   self.tableView.beginUpdates()
   self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

When i try to change the constraint's constant, i got the some constraint exceptions.

The one solution is here:

changing the priority

[How to change textview height constraint within table view cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107872/how-to-change-textview-height-constraint-within-table-view-cell)

Is there any other way to resolve this problem? and what is the proper way?

Comment: Solution of your question depends on your requirement and approach you have followed so first ask question like this **1)** add something about what you are trying to do in your post. **2)** What approach you have followed. **3)** What issue you are facing now.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy,  now understood?

Comment: Can you show me your prototype-cell!

Comment: I am not using storyboard.

Comment: Ok may be you have UI layout, I just wanted to know how your cell appeared on run time.

Comment: I got the solution. Thanks